# Getting general values of Pell-type equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $(3+2\sqrt2)^n=a+b\sqrt 2$, how to get the general $a$ and $b$ given that $\mathcal{a,b,n}\in \mathbb{Z}$

I don't want any recurrence relation. Please post the general solution for $a,b$ along with the method of approach to that general solution.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: I'm not sure there's a general formula for this...what is true is that $\;3+2\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt2)^2\;$ , and if you have studied a little about units in the ring $\;\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]\;$ this could help a little...

Comment: @EthanBolker Please no Recurrence relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a moment to convince yourself that if $(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n = a + b\sqrt{2}$, then $(3 - 2\sqrt{2})^n = a - b\sqrt{2}$.

Now you can get closed-form solutions for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n$ as follows:
$$a = \frac{(a + b\sqrt{2}) + (a - b\sqrt{2})}{2} = \frac{(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n + (3 - 2\sqrt{2})^n}{2};$$
$$b = \frac{(a + b\sqrt{2}) - (a - b\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n - (3 - 2\sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$